# How to use SAS multiple Macro variables in procedure block using loops only if it exist

Tags: loops, sorting, sas, procedure, sas-macro

I created multiple macro variables using call symput using data values and I wanted to use them in procedure block using loops in macro and it's not working out for me.

- Creating macro variables;

```
Data _null_;
  set all;
  n= _n_;
  n1 = strip(put(n, best.));
  call symput('seq'||n1, n1);
  *creates macro variables like sort1, sort2, sort3,....;
  if ~missing(var) then call symput('sort'||left(_n_), var);
run;
```

- finding no of records;

```
Proc sql noprint;
  select count(var) into:Noobs from all;
quit;

%put &Noobs
```

- Macro block;

```
%macro sortuntil(n= );
  %do i = 1 %to n;
     %let data = i;
     %do %until (&data eq &seq(i));
        Proc sort data = dif;
           by &sort1 &sort2 &sort3 &sort4 . . . etc;
        run;
      %end;
   %end;
%mend;

%sortuntil(n=&Noobs);
```

The above code should sort the data based on no of macro variables created in data *null* block
example: All dataset has 15 records in var variable so, in this case it execute below code

```
Proc sort data = dif;
             by &sort1 &sort1 &sort1 &sort1 &sort1 . . . sort15;
         run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easier ways to do this.  For example, you can use PROC SQL with SELECT INTO to create a single macro variable that will hold a list of variable names.  But if you're interested in macro looping, that approach can be used as well.  Note that your code has the looping wrong. You are running PROC SORT inside the loop, so if you call %SortUntil(n=15) it will run PROC SORT 15 times.  Instead you would want to use the loop to build the list of variables on the BY statement.  You could do that like:

```
data dif ;
x=1 ; y=2 ; z=3 ;
run ;

%let sort1=x ;
%let sort2=y ;
%let sort3=z ;

%macro sortuntil(n= );
  %local i ;
  proc sort data = dif;
    by
      %do i = 1 %to &n;
        &&sort&i
      %end ;
    ;
  run ;
%mend;

options mprint ;
%sortuntil(n=3)
%sortuntil(n=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your step to create the macro variables and your attempt to use them have trouble.

But let's start with your question of how to loop and evaluate a series of macro variables.   So if you had these two macro variables:

```
%let sort1=id;
%let sort2=date;
```

Then you could generate

```
by id date;
```

by running this code (inside a macro).

```
by 
%do i=1 %to 2 ;
  &&sort&i
%end;
;
```

So the first pass over &&sort&i the macro processor will convert && to & and &i to 1.  It then makes a second pass because of the && so it evaluates &sort1 to get ID.

Notice there is no semicolon inside the %DO loop so all of the text emitted inside the %DO loop can become part of a single SAS statement.

Your data step is working too hard.

First there is no reason to use the ancient CALL SYMPUT() method (unless you really need to insert leading or trailing spaces into the macro variable).  Use CALL SYMPUTX() instead.

And you can use CATS() to append the numeric suffix to the base macro variable names.

And it is also not counting the sort variables properly.   It would only work if the input dataset was sorted so that the all of the observations with non missing values of VAR are at the start of the data.  Otherwise instead of generating SORT1, SORT2 etc it might generate SORT3, SORT7, SORT11 etc.

So if you need use a data step to generate multiple sequences of macro variables, some of which have gaps, then you will want to keep your own counters for those shorter sequences.

```
data _null_;
  set all end=eof;
  call symputx(cats('seq',_n_),_n_);
  *creates macro variables like sort1, sort2, sort3,....;
  if not missing(var) then do;
     n+1;
     call symputx(cats('sort',n),nliteral(var));
  end;
  if eof then do; 
     call symputx('nsort',n);
     call symputx('nobs',_n_);
  end;
run;
```

PROC SQL can also generate macro variables, and for simple things it is easier than the data step.

To generate the series of SORT variables you could just do this:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select nliteral(var) into :sort1- 
  from all 
  where not missing(var)
  ;
%let nsort=&sqlobs;
quit;
```

But if the only use for the SORT... macro variables is to generate that BY statement then why not just put them all into ONE macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select nliteral(var) into :sortvars separated by ' '
  from all 
  where not missing(var)
  ;
%let nsort=&sqlobs;
quit;
```

Then you can just use that one macro variable in the BY statement and skip the looping.

```
by &sortvars ;
```